# How can I know that I exist (Using Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, existential-operator

How can I prove my existence using lines of code, is there a way an interaction between me and my CLI can provide me with assurance I exist, that everything around me is not a lie or unreal?

Comment: Seems like some stuff you are smokin

Comment: Dafuq? It's always 4:20 somewhere?

Comment: Hi, are you OK?

Comment: Is this talking about you as a person?

Comment: `python3 -c 'print("I exist")'`

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
python -c "import this" | sed -n '14p'
```

Comment: For those on Windows or on phones: "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess."

Answer (score 0):

Inside a class:

```
class Entity:
    def do_I_exist(self=None):
        if self:
            return True
        return False
```

You can call it either as an instance method or a class method:

```
>>> Entity.do_I_exist()
False
>>> Entity().do_I_exist()
True
```

If called as an instance method on an object, then it must be the case that the object exists. If called as a class method, it returns false, showing that no such object exists.

---

Outside the code this can be considered a matter of philosophy, and thus out of scope. The Wikipedia page on [cogito, ergo sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum) may be helpful for you in solving this dilemma.